# Select values substituting the values of other column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like this :-

```
A        B
28496   TS_28496_FX                        
7365    TS_7365_FX                         
14760   TS_14760_FX   
222     TS_222_AA1
```

I want to find all the records for column B which does not match the pattern

```
 'TS_' || A || '_FX'
```

So this shows me the only result

```
222     TS_222_AA1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a way:

```
with yourData(A,B) as (
    select '28496'   ,'TS_28496_FX' from dual union all                       
    select '7365'    ,'TS_7365_FX'  from dual union all                         
    select '14760'   ,'TS_14760_FX' from dual union all   
    select '222'     ,'TS_222_AA1'  from dual union all   
    select '999'     ,'999'         from dual
)
select *
from yourData
where B != 'TS_' || A || '_FX'
```

which gives:

```
A     B          
----- -----------
222   TS_222_AA1 
999   999
```

This assumes that `B` always `is not null`; otherwise you may use

```
where nvl(B, '-')  != 'TS_' || A || '_FX'
```